# i make a side menu，but PanResponder not work on phone

Tags: react-native

i make a side menu，**it's ok on genymotion**，but not work on my phone. it's response is delay more than 10s and most times not response on phone。please help me !

At the beginning ，I think it's flow reason:
1、position: 'absolute'
2、PanResponder wrapper a touchable

i had try clean this，but it's also not work。maybe its a bug ,are you ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4gj7.png)

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {
 View,
 Text,
 StyleSheet,
 ScrollView,
 Alert,
 PanResponder,
 TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native'
import {get_pointBaikeCate} from 'api'
import {Touchable} from 'basic'


export default class PointBaike extends Component {
 static navigationOptions = {
  title: '穴位百科',
  header: null
 }
 
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
   info: []
  }
  
  this.scrollY = []
 }
 
 async getInfo() {
  let res = await get_pointBaikeCate();
  console.log(res)
  
  // let info = [];
  // res.data.map((r)=> {
  //  r.content.map(c=> {
  //   let flag = info.find((item)=> {
  //    return item.jl == c.jl
  //   })
  //   if (flag) {
  //    flag.xw += `,${c.xw}`
  //   } else {
  //    info.push({
  //     jl: c.jl,
  //     xw: c.xw
  //    })
  //   }
  //  })
  // });
  //
  // // 对info的xw进行过滤
  // info = info.map((item)=> {
  //  let xw = item.xw.split(/[,|]/)
  //  item.xw = [...new Set(xw)].filter((x)=> {
  //   return x
  //  })
  //  return item
  // });
  
  this.setState({
   info: res.data
  })
 }
 
 goDetail(item) {
  let {navigate} = this.props.navigation
  console.log(item)
  navigate('PointBaikeDetail', {
   item
  })
 }
 
 componentWillMount() {
  this.getInfo()
  
  this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
   onStartShouldSetPanResponder: this._handleStartShouldSetPanResponder.bind(this),
   onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: this._handleStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture.bind(this),
   onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: this._handlerMoveShouldSetPanResponder.bind(this),
   onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: this._handleMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture.bind(this),
   onPanResponderTerminationRequest: this._handleMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture,
   onPanResponderMove: this._handlePanResponderMove.bind(this),
  });
 }
 _handlerMoveShouldSetPanResponder(evt, gestureState){
  if (gestureState.dx != 0 && gestureState.dy == 0) {
   return true;
  }
  return false;
 }
 
 _handleMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture(evt, gestureState) {
  return gestureState.dx != 0 && gestureState.dy != 0
 }
 
 _handleStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture(evt, gestureState) {
  return gestureState.dx != 0 && gestureState.dy != 0;
 }
 
 _handleMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture(evt, gestureState) {
  return gestureState.dx != 0 && gestureState.dy != 0;
 }
 
 _scrollTo(index) {
  // Alert.alert('索引', `${index}`)
  
  this._scrollView.scrollTo({y: this.scrollY[index]})
 }
 
 _handleStartShouldSetPanResponder() {
  return true
 }
 
 _handlePanResponderMove(e, gestureState) {
  // console.log('滑动', e.nativeEvent.pageY)
  // 计算手指在那个元素上，得出index，然后根据index设置scrollTop
  let y = e.nativeEvent.pageY - 100
  let index = Math.ceil(y / 20) - 1
  console.log(index, this)
  
  this._scrollView.scrollTo({y: this.scrollY[index]})
 }
 
 
 _onLayout({nativeEvent}) {
  this.scrollY.push(nativeEvent.layout.y)
 }
 
 render() {
  let {info} = this.state
  return (
   <View style={styles.wrapper}>
    
    <ScrollView style={{flex: 1, height: 300}}
                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                ref={(e)=> {
                 this._scrollView = e
                }}
    >
     {
      info.map((item, i)=> {
       return (
        <View key={i} style={styles.lists}
              onLayout={this._onLayout.bind(this)}
        >
         <View>
          <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
         </View>
         <View style={styles.listBox}>
          
          {
           item.list.map((x, xi)=> {
            return (
             <Touchable key={xi}
                        onPress={this.goDetail.bind(this, x)}
             >
              <View style={styles.list}>
               <Text
                style={styles.text}>{x.title}</Text>
              </View>
             </Touchable>
            )
           })
          }
         </View>
        </View>
       )
      })
     }
     <View style={{height: 100}}></View>
    </ScrollView>
    <View style={styles.sideMenu}
          {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}
    >
     {
      info.map((item, i)=> {
       return (
        <TouchableOpacity key={i} onPress={this._scrollTo.bind(this, i)}>
         <View>
          <Text
           style={styles.sideText}>{item.title.charAt(3) || item.title.charAt(0)}</Text>
         </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
       )
      })
     }
    </View>
   </View>
  )
 }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 wrapper: {
  paddingLeft: 6,
  paddingRight: 6,
  paddingTop: 10,
  paddingBottom: 10,
  flex: 1,
  backgroundColor: '#fff'
 },
 sideText: {
  width: 25,
  height: 20,
  lineHeight: 20,
  textAlign: 'center'
 },
 sideMenu: {
  position: 'absolute',
  right: 0,
  top: 100,
  zIndex: 100,
  backgroundColor: '#eee'
 },
 lists: {},
 listBox: {
  flexDirection: 'row',
  flexWrap: 'wrap'
 },
 list: {
  width: (WinWidth - 20) / 5,
 },
 title: {
  fontSize: 18,
  color: DEFAULT_COLOR,
  paddingTop: 14,
  paddingBottom: 10
 },
 text: {
  flex: 1,
  textAlign: 'center',
  paddingTop: 10,
  paddingBottom: 10,
 }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.getInfo()

    this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
        onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
        onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: this._handleStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture.bind(this),
        onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: this._handlerMoveShouldSetPanResponder.bind(this),
        onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: this._handleMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture.bind(this),
        onPanResponderTerminationRequest: this._handleMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture,
        onPanResponderMove: this._handlePanResponderMove.bind(this),
    });
}
```

Comment: click the menu is ok,but panResponderMove is delay too , but it's ok on genymotion .